# Shop vs store classification

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is there a special name for shops where only clothing ( also maybe shoes) is sold for example like Zara or Mango ..Are they shop or store ?

And also for example would you call shop or store or market small Tescos in the UK ?

And also for example would you call shop or store or market big ones like Sainsbury's  in the UK  / Walmart in the US ?

and how about Mark and Spencer?

Comment: The names differ based on location (for instance, between the UK and US). Which are you interested in?

Comment: @cpast I would like to learn both actually

Answer (score 3):

British English:

A shop that only sells clothing (or clothing and shoes) is a clothes shop.

A small Tesco (i.e. a Tesco Metro) could be called any of the following:

> The shop
>
> The shops (if there's at least one other shop nearby)
>
> The local shop
>
> The corner shop (does not have to be on a corner)
>
> The off-license (if it sells alcohol)
>
> The offie (short for off-license)
>
> The convenience store (if you work in marketing)

A larger Tesco, Sainsburys, Morrisons, etc. is a supermarket.

Marks and Spencer is a clothes shop, but it's also a department store, since most branches also have a food hall and home wares.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Variations will probably apply, as this sort of thing is rarely "hard-and-fast" in English. This answer is from a US perspective.</sub>

> Is there a special name for shops where only clothing (also maybe shoes) sold for example Zara or Mango?

I would call this a **clothing store**. I probably wouldn't call it a *shop* unless they did a lot of on-site alterations.

There are also **department stores**. These are named because the store has several departments all under one roof. For example, a typical department store might have:

- a *clothing section* (where I could by some socks or shoes),
- a *furnishings section* (where I could buy some drapes or a wall clock),
- a *sporting goods section* (where I could by a tennis racquet and a dozen golf balls),
- a *office supply section* (where I could buy a stapler and a ream of paper), and
- an *electronics section* (where I could by a television and a new case for my iPhone).

There are also **chain stores**, where you'll find several of same stores as you travel from city to city. This is where the taxonomy gets tricky, though, because several chain stores are department stores, and vice-versa.

More recently, some department stores have added a grocery section; these often get labeled with the prefix *super-*. So, a Wal-Mart may be a department store, but a Super Wal-Mart (or Wal-Mart Supercenter) is a department store with a full service grocery store in the building.

[image]

Chain stores that are *not* department stores could be classified generically as **specialty stores**, and more specifically as the kind of store they are (such as grocery stores, sporting goods stores, office supply stores, chain pharmacies, etc.)

Comment: Why does "shop" imply that they do alterations?

Comment: Thanks .I got your answer. The thing I could not understand is the sentence " I probably wouldn't call it a shop unless they did a lot of on-site alterations."  What do you mean by that? Can you  please explain ?  and I just saw how about the term "convenient store". Do you use it in the US? I think they are more like a chain stores named their brand  names with the word "express"

Comment: @Mrt "[Convenience store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenience_store)" (more recently shortened to "c-store") is often a corner store that is attached to a gas station (petrol station). They generally sell automotive items along with tobacco products, snacks, beverages, and even basic kitchen and other household staples though at highly inflated prices.... you pay extra for the "convenience" of not having to go to a grocer.

Comment: @Catija I see. Is there a special name for small and maybe located on a corner in a residential area ( not near a highway )?

Comment: @Mrt I'm sure that "convenience store" or "corner store" (or "c-store") would be perfectly acceptable, assuming they're just selling general items. (in the US)

Comment: @Catija "convenience store" or "corner store" are could be used as a general term for small grocery stores ?

Comment: @Mrt Have you even looked at the Convenience store Wikipedia page I linked to?

Comment: @Cat - Mostly because I'd probably places like Ann Taylor or The Gap a clothing _store_, rather than a clothing _shop_ – although the latter would be acceptable. However, if we change the store from a typical mall clothing outlet to a small, independent place with alterations in the back, and I might lean toward calling it a _shop_ instead. (_Shop_ seems like a more apt word for a place with plenty of scissors, pins, and measuring tape.) As I said up front, though, none of this is hard-and-fast.